# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY on installing apk (No Google APIs)

Tags: android

I have a problem installing my android app with a custom library: hessian-3.1.5.jar. My IDE is: intellij idea 11

This library is in the project structure's library and in AndroidManifest.xml I have the line: `<uses-library android:name="com.caucho.hessian.client" />`

But it says: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work on the emulator?  It sounds like your device doesn't have the Google libraries on it (and since they're licensed to device builders, if it doesn't have them you can't get them onto it).

Comment: It would be better to ask additional question in comments